# stop avahi on archlinux

Tags: samba, arch-linux, avahi

I have archlinux with samba.

I noticed from last update it started avahi-daemon.

If I stop/disable avahi, seems samba starting avahi automatically. Also tried with kill.

Printing is disabled in samba.

How can I prevent samba to start avahi after samba start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line to your `smb.conf` and it should do the trick.

```
multicast dns register = no
```

Comment: Yee!!! Works!!!